# ASP.NET MVC application running II6 with wildcard mapping using only 3 threads

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, multithreading, iis-6

During the performance testing of our ASP.NET MVC application I discovered interesting bottle neck. **The application is using only 3 managed threads**.

- I checked maximum thread pool size. It's 200 and we are having 197 available threads.
- I checked connection limit of web site and it's unlimited.
- I tried to run stress test locally against Cassini and application used 50 threads.

The application is running on dedicated virtual Windows Server 2003 Web Edition SP2 server with IIS6 with the wildcard mapping.

Do you have any idea what may be wrong?

---

**Edit**: It's really weird. I tried it today and had about 20 threads which is reasonable count.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this article:

**Monitoring Threads in IIS6**
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/a63ee1c2-04d6-44dc-b4d6-678eb3117bf9.mspx?mfr=true

There might be something there that may help.

Comment: I am not sure if it help because problem disappeared but at least it's interesting reading.